# Optimal data structure for streaming data

Tags: python, containers

I have a stream of data of the form `[id, name, act, value, type]`.

`id` is an integer, `name` a string, `act` can be 'add', 'update' or 'delete', `value` is an integer, `type` is either `L` or `R`. We can only add once an `id`, perform multiple updates and then delete the `id`. I obviously look for a data structure that will allow me to insert those data efficiently.

I also need to be able to get the highest `L` value by `name` and the lowest `R` value by `name` at each moment the fastest way possible.

I believe I will need to use heap to get in a constant time `min` and `max` values by `name`. My problem is that I don't manage to find a way to also have the possibility to delete and update existing data at the same time.

Comment: BST and dictionary to each node? or just try pandas dataframe.

Comment: please share some testable data samples and the cases of their life-cycle changes

Comment: @YongkangZhao I have a hard time finding a way to implement such data structure. That's what came in my mind first but how do you compare two dictionaries within the BST?

Comment: I don't think you want to compare anything, just use dictionary to find whatever it is you are looking for directly. if you are updating just delete that node from bst and insert a new one

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing is a bit unclear here. Let me try and rephrase: you are looking for a good data structure such that, given a stream of operations in the form given above, you can add, delete, or update items (found using their id number). And you'd also like to maintain a few summary statistics about the whole data structure such as highest L and lowest R value.

Does this sound correct?

A dictionary of dictionaries sounds like it's probably the right answer if your id numbers are not over a specific range, or a list of dictionaries if they are.

Comment: will a dict of dict enough to maintain the order between values?

Comment: Which item are you ordering the values by?

Comment: By their respective names.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting makes this a different sort of problem. So you are instead looking for a way to add and subtract data entries into a data structure sorted alphabetically on their string names? One common way to do this is with a binary search tree. A BST will give you an insertion time complexity of O(log(n)) with n elements in the tree. At each element you can store the other data. Then you can separately maintain the highest L and lowest R values and update these each time a value is added that exceeds on of these values. If you remove a value equal to one of these limits, you'll have to traverse the whole data structure to get the new limit value.

Comment: My bad if I explained badly. I want to be able to get the highest L values and the lowest R values FOR each names. In an environment where I get streaming data, I think that means to order directly values from lowest to highest (and vice versa) for each names as soon as I insert a new value. No need to order the strings.